# Connection refused between PC(Linux) and RPi using Python socket

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming

I encountered a big problem, that I couldn't resolve. I try to check multiple answers but without results. Main task: connection between PC and Raspberry Pi uses TCP/IP Ethernet.
My codes looks like this:
Server:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(),1234))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    client, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} succesfully!")
    client.send(bytes("Hello!", "utf-8"))
s.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(),1234))
Message = "HeloWorld!"
s.send(byte(Message))

s.close()
```

> The error is: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

What should I do?

Comment: Nothing was listening at the IP:port you are trying to connect to. It's a bit optimistic trying to get a meaningful hostname from a socket that isn't connected to anything yet. Try using the target host's IP address or hostname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are mixed up functions.
[`socket.gethostname()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostname):

> Return a **string containing the hostname** of the machine where the
>   Python interpreter is currently executing.

You can check it:

```
print socket.gethostname()
```

But [`socket.connect()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect) function wants an **address** (which depends on protocol family). Thus you probably want to use IP addresses of your hosts or resolve domain names of hosts to IP addresses through [`socket.gethostbyname()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname).

Also you have several typos. To make it work (commented lines for the case when both client and server are on the same host), try:
Server:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#s.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 31337))

# suppose 192.168.0.2 is IP of one of your server's network interfaces
s.bind(("192.168.0.2", 31337))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    client, address = s.accept()
    print "Connection from ", address, ", message:", client.recv(32)
    client.send(bytes("WTF"))
s.close()
```

Client:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#s.connect((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 31337))
s.connect(("192.168.0.2", 31337))
s.send(bytes("Hello, World!"))
print "Message from server: ", s.recv(32)
s.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually the problem is, that when I want to get my PC address  I only get this message:
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::5be5:39b4:497:1281  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
The computers IP isn't showing.

Comment: @Fellon You have to configure IP settings and then check the network connectivity between your hosts (e.g. through [`ping`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping), if the firewall allows it) before trying to do TCP exchange. If my answer helped you, you can mark it as accepted.